# Fragment page not displaying for MediaPlayer Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-music-player

I want to make a music player in my fragment page for my android app using android studio. There is no error to the code however when i run the code the fragment page is not appearing the audio player. i follow the code from youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJ3XbXtjNaE&t=385s

this is the code

fragment_med1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/scene"
    tools:context=".Med1Fragment">

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="250dp"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_music_note_24"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/player_position"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/player_duration"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/bt_rew"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_fast_rewind_24"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/bt_play"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/bt_pause"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/bt_ff"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_fast_forward_24"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Med1Fragment.java

```java
public class Med1Fragment extends Fragment {

    TextView playerposition, playerduration;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    ImageView btnrew, btnplay, btnpause, btnff;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        playerposition = playerposition.findViewById(R.id.player_position);
        playerduration = playerduration.findViewById(R.id.player_duration);
        seekBar = seekBar.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        btnrew = btnrew.findViewById(R.id.bt_rew);
        btnplay = btnplay.findViewById(R.id.bt_play);
        btnpause = btnpause.findViewById(R.id.bt_pause);
        btnff = btnff.findViewById(R.id.bt_ff);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.meditation2);


        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        };

        int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        String sDuration = convertFormat(duration);
        playerduration.setText(sDuration);

        btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnpause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,0);
            }
        });

        btnpause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnpause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        });

        btnff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentposition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && duration != currentposition){
                    currentposition = currentposition + 5000;
                    playerposition.setText(convertFormat(currentposition));
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentposition);
                }
            }
        });

        btnrew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentposition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && currentposition > 5000){
                    currentposition = currentposition - 5000;
                    playerposition.setText(convertFormat(currentposition));
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentposition);
                }
            }
        });

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
                playerposition.setText(convertFormat(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                btnpause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            }
        });


    }
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        private String convertFormat(int duration){
            return String.format("%02d:%02d"
                    , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)
                    , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                     TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));

        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_med1, container, false);
    }

}
```

I am always confused to write the code for fragment because the usual code i get/learn from (eg:youtube) are written for activity instead of fragment.

really appreciate some help. thank you.